# Where does ExtJS's store keeps all the data

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-stores

I want to know where does ExtJS store keeps all the data? I know the data is stored in the memory but I want to know does it used HTML 5 local storage internally or if any other technique is employed?

Thanks,
Deepesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

In every case, the data of the store is stored in a Javascript object. The store persists its data via a proxy. It is a matter of configuration how this data is stored. You can configure different types of proxies:

Client side storage

- LocalStorageProxy - saves its data to localStorage if the browser supports it
- SessionStorageProxy - saves its data to sessionStorage if the browsers supports it
- MemoryProxy - holds data in memory only, any data is lost when the page is refreshed

Server side storage

- Ajax - sends requests to a server on the same domain
- JsonP - uses JSON-P to send requests to a server on a different domain
- Rest - uses RESTful HTTP methods (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) to communicate with server
- Direct - uses Ext.direct.Manager to send requests

More details are [in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When LocalStorageProxy & SessionStorageProxy are used, does system persists the data even when page is refereshed?

Comment: Yes, for SessionStorage, data is persisted until the session is destroyed, for LocalStorage, data is persisted until the user clears the HTML5 LocalStorage cache.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have one more question. How do you define a session in ExtJs context ?

Comment: sessionStorage is not Ext related. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp says: *The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the browser window.* I don't use this, I use server side storage in my project. So I don't have experience with local and session storage

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in an in memory collection called a `MixedCollection`. It's an ordered collection, but it also allows you to look up data by key, so it's like having an ordered hashmap.